# Выбор ячеек в библиотеке PHPExcel

Tags: php

Мне необходимо обратиться к конкретным 2-м столбцам Excel и обрабатывать их содержимое.
Алгоритм простой:

1. Выбор значения из 2-го столбца;
2. Сравнение значения 2-го столбца с допустимыми (whitelist);
3. Если значение 2-го столбца присутствует в whitelist'e, то извлечение данных из 1-го столбца в массив
4. Повторение действия для следующей строки.

На данный момент есть простой код, который просто выводит все содержимое Excel файла в таблицу html.

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('testSmeta.xlsx');
    
foreach($excel ->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
 $lists[] = $worksheet->toArray();
}
    
foreach($lists as $list){
 echo '<table border="1">';
 // Перебор строк
     foreach($list as $row){
       echo '<tr>';
       // Перебор столбцов
       foreach($row as $col){
         echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
     }
     echo '</tr>';
     }
 echo '</table>';
}


?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу взять значения из ячеек и организовать цикл прохода по 2 столбцам.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как мне кажется - разобрался. В итоге код получился таким:

```
 <?php

// Подключаем библиотеку
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('ElectricLightingSmeta.xlsx');

// Цикл по листам Excel-файла
foreach ($pExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    // выгружаем данные из объекта в массив
    $tables[] = $worksheet->toArray();
}
$whitelist_units = array("м3","м3.","м2","м2.","м","м.","т","т.","кг","кг.","шт","шт.","баллон"); //Лист допустимых ед. измерения
$materials_arr = array(); //Объявление результирующего массива наименований
$row=1; //Стартовая строка для поиска
$col_units=3;  //Колонка в которой должна быть найдены еденицы измерений, по умолчанию 3 (D)
$col_materials_name=2; //Колонка наименований материалов
$search_row_units = ""; //Массив для условия завершения поиска едениц измерения
$search_row_end = ""; 
// выбираем лист, с которым будем работать
$pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet();

// БЛОК АНАЛИЗА - Поиск ячейки с еденицей измерения в колонке D 
while ($search_row_units !== "Ед. изм.") {
        // получаем доступ к ячейке по номеру строки 
        // (нумерация с единицы) и столбца (нумерация с нуля) 
        $cell = $aSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_units, $row);
        // читаем значение ячейки
        $search_row_units = $cell->getValue();

        $row= $row+1;

}

$end_row = $row; 
 //find_end_row-1 переменная, в которой будет содержаться номер строки, которая служит маяком конца работы цикла обработки

while ($search_row_end !== "Итого прямые затраты по смете в текущих ценах") {
        // получаем доступ к ячейке по номеру строки 
        // (нумерация с единицы) и столбца (нумерация с нуля) 
        $cell = $aSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $end_row);
        $search_row_end
         = $cell->getValue();        
        $end_row= $end_row+1;

}

$end_row = $end_row-1;

echo "*ВНИМАНИЕ*<br/> НАЙДЕНАЯ СТРОКА ЕДЕНИЦ ИЗМЕРЕНИЯ: ",$row,"<br/> СТРОКА ЗАВЕРШЕНИЯ ОБРАБОТКИ: ", $end_row,"<br/>"; //Промежуточный алерт, на этом этапе в $row хранится строка Ед. измерений

$start_format_row = $row;

// БЛОК ФОРМАТИРОВАНИЯ - устранение RichText - ситуации, когда в одной ячейке текст с разным формативанием. Если это не устранить, возможны проблемы с дальнейшей обработкой массива наименований материалов. После выполнения работы, он перезаписывает исходный файл, потом он снова загружается в блоке выборки.

while ($start_format_row != $end_row) {
       $aSheet->getStyle($col_materials_name, $start_format_row)->applyFromArray($false_format_style);
       $aSheet->getStyle($col_materials_name, $start_format_row)->applyFromArray($true_format_style);
       $start_format_row= $start_format_row+1;

}

echo "<br>Форматирование завершено <br>";

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($pExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('FORMAT_SRC.xlsx');

$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('FORMAT_SRC.xlsx');


// БЛОК ВЫБОРКИ ИНФОРМАЦИИ - Выбор значений ячеек наименования материала по условию вхождения их едениц измерений в whitelist_units  


  while ($row != $end_row) {
       // получаем доступ к ячейке по номеру строки 
       // (нумерация с единицы) и столбца (нумерация с нуля) 
       $cell = $aSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_units, $row);
       // читаем значение ячейки
       $unit = $cell->getValue();


      if (in_array($unit, $whitelist_units)) {
          // получаем доступ к ячейке по номеру строки 
          // (нумерация с единицы) и столбца (нумерация с нуля) 
          $cell = $aSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_materials_name, $row);
          // читаем значение ячейки
          $value = $cell->getValue();
          array_push($materials_arr, $value);


          $row = $row+1;

      } else {
          $row = $row+1;
      }


  }

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($pExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('Result_smeta.xlsx');

  echo "<br/>--------------------------------------------------<br/><br/>";
  print_r($materials_arr);
?>
```

Если необходимы пояснения, пишите :D

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно.

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('testSmeta.xlsx');
 //Получение массива с прочитанного с Excel файла
        $sheetColumns = $exce->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Лист1')->toArray();

//перебираем полученый масив
foreach($sheetColumns as $key = $val){
.... 
}
```